# How to avoid bad orientation showing picture then use UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using `UIImagePickerController` to take a picture in my Objective C app. Then take the picture with camera or load this from gallery I show this in `UIImageView`. Here is my problem, the picture show rotate 90º if this was take in portrait orientation device...

[image]

[image]

If I get orientation of `UIImage` to show in `UIImageView`, always get `UIImageOrientationUp`, so I can't rotate this manually...

```
 if (photo.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
    NSLog(@"UP"); //Always get this line. If Uiimage is portrait or landscape
}else if (photo.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
    NSLog(@"Right");
}
```

I', trying use functions like:

```
 - (UIImage *)fixrotation:(UIImage *)image{
...
}
```

But the picture doesn't rotate. Because I get always `UIImageOrientationUp`..

How can solve this and show my picture always in portrait position in my `UIImageView`?

My didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is:

```
   -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

 //I use this image to show in next View
SecondView * controller = [SecondView new];
controller.imageView.image = image;
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue2" sender:self];
[picker.self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
```

And then in a ThirdView assign this to UIImageView between other segue:
    //photo is the variable to get  from segue
     UIImage *imageToDisplay = photo.fixOrientation;

```
self.imageV.image = imageToDisplay;
self.imageV.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your UIImagePickerDelegateMethod didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo and where you set the image within the UIImageView? Cheers

Comment: So your image is displayed on a UIImageView on SecondView viewController? On the storyboard can you check if the orientation of the SecondView is set to Landscape (within the attributes panel for that VC). If it is, then this is why it'll be showing in landscape (rotated 90* from main VC that is).

Comment: No, is correctly, all view is portrait. But I see trying things that if I use fixOrientation in didFinishPick it show that picture have UIImageOrientationRight. But if I apply - (UIImage *)fixOrientation  this remains unrotated in the next View.

Answer (score 0):

Use category for this

**UIImage+fixOrientation.h**

```
@interface UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation;

@end
```

**UIImage+fixOrientation.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (fixOrientation)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

// No-op if the orientation is already correct
if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

// We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
// We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        break;
}

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        break;
}

// Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
// calculated above.
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
        break;
}

// And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return img;
}

@end
```

Comment: I used your classes but this not apply the fixorientation. I import: #import "UIImage+fixOrientation.h" And then call function to my photo variable - > UIImage *imageToDisplay = photo.fixOrientation; But this not works.. Am I doing something bad??

Comment: I am debugging with NSLog and I can see always execute if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp){ altought the picture was take in portrait position :(

Comment: try to add shouldAutoRotate() method (which returns No) in your viewController

Comment: If I open the picker in portrait, is like metadata obtain this information, and then when I want to show this get position when was taken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing that problem.
This code must resolve issue:

```
UIImage *initialImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(initialImage);

UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImage *fixedOrientationImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:tempImage.CGImage
                                       scale:initialImage.scale
                             orientation:initialImage.imageOrientation];
```